How can I receive the responses to my broadcast requests through PF?
My server's pf.conf file has these lines (among others for other protocols):
block in proto udp all
pass out proto udp all

Now this server needs to check the state of some neighboring machines through UDP broadcast:

It opens a UDP socket on any address; the OS assigns it a port
It uses this socket to send a broadcast UDP message toward a well-defined port
The host around in the same network reply to this message with a unicast or broadcast reply to the same port used by the server
The server registers these responses and can tell if any of the neighboring machines are down

To give an example:

My server 192.168.1.1 sends a UDP packet 192.168.1.1:52361 -> 192.168.1.255:4545
Host 192.168.1.3 replies with 192.168.1.3:4545 -> 192.168.1.1:52361
Host 192.168.1.4 replies with 192.168.1.4:37243 -> 192.168.1.1:52361
Host 192.168.1.5 replies with 192.168.1.5:4545 -> 255.255.255.255:52361
The server registers that 192.168.1.{3,4,5} are up and running.

Now the problem is that PF is preventing my application from receiving these responses. Tcpdump shows that the responses are flowing in, but the application does not receive anything. If I disable pf, i get the responses I expect.
What can I add to pf.conf to get the responses?

this is why custom protocol helpers for packet filters exist — they know more about the upper levels than just L3 and 4. In this very case I think the best scenario would be short term open reply window — only when server sent its initial broadcast. But that might be tedious to implement anyway.

Since src and dst IPs are different in the request (192.168.1.1,192.168.1.255) and subsequent responses (192.168.1.*,255.255.255.255), the state kept for the request won't be enough to allow incoming responses.
You can allow all incoming packets to the broadcast address coming from the desired source port (e.g. 52361):
pass in proto udp from any port 52361 to 255.255.255.255

You could also allow responses on the interface's broadcast address (e.g. for eth0):
pass in proto udp from any port 52361 to {eth0:broadcast,255.255.255.255}

